# Strategies to help deal with JavaScript application error logging

Tags: javascript, logging, reporting

I'm currently developing a medium-sized JavaScript (RightJS+Canvas) application. It's pretty close to getting deployed on larger scale.

As we all know users tend to come by the weirdest issues. They can break an app in ways you just cannot fathom. Therefore I thought it might be cool to provide the users some way to report possible issues back.

Most of my users aren't technically proficient. They don't know debuggers ie. tools. They just want to use the app.

This brings me to the actual problem: Are there some common strategies/technical solutions that make it possible for the users to report issues they have come by? It would be great if they could provide some debug information (error log as in Firebug) to the server using some simple reporting mechanism without having to resort to some actual tool.

Any ideas on how to proceed with this problem are welcome. :)

Comment: I guess without a debugger you would have to catch all errors, put them in some object and let user write comments before sending it via AJAX

Comment: Just a quick comment... As a temporary crutch I added Firebug Lite (http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite) to the app. In case the users run into troubles, at least they can provide log output to me. It's not automatic but better than nothing. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like since I asked the question multiple services have come up. I have listed some of these below:

- [Muscula](http://www.muscula.com/)
- [Track:js](http://trackjs.com/)
- [JSLogger](http://jslogger.com/)
- [Errormator](https://errormator.com/)
- [Debuggify](https://www.debuggify.net/)
- [ErrorBoard](https://github.com/Lapple/ErrorBoard)